# How to obtain pure alcohol from mixture of alcohol & carbonyl? (Grignard experiment)

Tags: organic-chemistry, purification

If one discovers that after finishing up a Grignard reaction that their alcohol product has been contaminated with the carbonyl starting material, how could they separate the alcohol from the carbonyl compound to obtain a purified alcohol product?

I was thinking that they could recrystallize the contaminated product using an alcohol as a solvent, but is there a better option for separating these two compounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rather doubt that there is a better option **in general**. Other possible methods are

- distillation
  To give an example, acetone has a boiling point of 56 °C, while *tert*-butanol boils at 82 °C.
- column chromatography on silica

But in many cases, your suggestion to separate the compounds by crystallization is a good idea. This is in particular true when your product has a high boiling point and/or you have to purify large amounts of substance.